# With the "small" Mac keyboard, how to simulate a HOME, END, and PageUp, PageDown key?

Tags: itunes, finder, keyboard

My desk is a little too narrow for the long type of Apple keyboard -- the one that has the keypad and the <kbd>Home ↖</kbd>, <kbd>End ↘</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up ⇞</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down ⇟</kbd> keys...  (it will take up the space for the mouse).

So if the small (wireless) keyboard is used, is there a way to simulate these keys: <kbd>Home ↖</kbd>, <kbd>End ↘</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up ⇞</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down ⇟</kbd>?  (<kbd>Home ↖</kbd> takes a user to beginning of page, <kbd>End ↘</kbd> takes the user to end of page).

In some apps like Chrome and Safari, <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Up ↑</kbd> is like <kbd>Home ↖</kbd>, and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↓ Down</kbd> is like <kbd>End ↘</kbd>.  <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Up ↑</kbd> is like <kbd>Page Up ⇞</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↓ Down</kbd> is like <kbd>Page Down ⇟</kbd>, but it won't work in some apps such as in Finder (File Manager) and iTunes, where both of them will only do PageUp and PageDown simulation but not <kbd>Home ↖</kbd> or<kbd>End ↘</kbd> simulation.

I have this keyboard:
[image: Apple keyboard]
Not this keyboard (which has the dedicated <kbd>Home ↖</kbd>, <kbd>End ↘</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up ⇞</kbd>, and <kbd>Page Down ⇟</kbd> keys):
[image: Apple extended keyboard]

Comment: Worth noting that the same applies for MacBook keyboards.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> keys you mentioned for Chrome and Safari are coincidences. The <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> keys are not. Those key combinations are actually mapped to the Page up/Page down keycodes, so the application thinks you actually pressed those keys. There are similar mappings for Home and End: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, respectively. These <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> mappings will work exactly like Page Up/Down and Home/End in any application, unless it somehow is working around the system.

Comment: perfect!  why didn't I think of that!

Comment: This is great if you can use two hands. But is there a way to do this with only one hand? I cannot spread my fingers far enough to operate both 'Fn' and 'arrow up' or 'arrow down' simultaneously.

Comment: @Mark I don't know of another combination. You could turn on Sticky keys in System Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard, which would let you press fn then the arrow separately.

Comment: For Windows Remote Desktop, you can use: fn+control+left/right for control+Home and control+End. fn+control+up/down for PageUp and PageDown.